# How to run a simulator with iOS 15 (5.5 inch iPhone 8 Plus) to take some screenshots for the submission when using Swift Data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi I have been struggling to run the simulator to take some screenshots for uploading the app with Swift.

I am required to run a 5.5 inch simulator, which is a iPhone 8 plus, but the problem is that the simulator cannot run the program with Swift data (only for ios17?)

How can I fix this issue? Thank you.

Here is the error that I encounter with ios 15.0 to run the simulator
modelContainer(for:inMemory:isAutosaveEnabled:isUndoEnabled:onSetup:)' is only available in iOS 17.0

Comment: Why use SwiftData when you need to support older iOS versions? Maybe you could get around this by using the `available` attribute but you would then need another storage solution for earlier os versions which sound very complicated. The most straightforward solution is to only support iOS 17 or replacing SwiftData altogether with Core Data

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for your comments. It's because the newest ios that iPhone 8 plus (5.5 inches) is ios 15.0, which does not support swift data I guess. What should I do?

Comment: I don't have any other advice than the last sentence in my previous comment, there is no silver bullet here as far as I know.

Comment: If it is just `...to take some screenshots for uploading the app`,
 then run the iPhone8 simulator with just a basic Swift app, anything will do.
 Then run your real code with an iPhone ios17 compatible simulator, and copy and paste
 the picture on top of the iPhone8 display. 
 Adjust the size and create what looks like an iPhone8 running your App.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for your comment. I see but I am wondering if everyone takes this approach when they upload the screenshots.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't need to use ios15. That would be cool if I could simulate my app on iPhone 8 plus with ios 17.2 but I am clueless.

Comment: iPhone8, can have max ios-16 on it, not ios-17. 
 But you could use iPhone SE (gen 3 or 2) instead. Seems to be the same size and looks and have ios-17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bit of an anomaly that you are required to provide a screenshot for a device which cannot run the app.

An iPhone 8 Plus can run iOS 16, but as you point out, it cannot run iOS 17. The only other devices with the same screen size are even older iPhones, so that doesn't help either.

However, what this means is that your app is never going to be installed on a phone with a 5.5 inch screen. So the screenshots will probably never be seen. So it doesn't really matter what they show.

I would suggest uploading a single screenshot that explains the circumstances. Something like:

[image: AppNotAvailable]